# Why won't BigQuery let me select a part of my query?

Tags: google-chrome, google-bigquery

I'm working in BigQuery studio. Whenever I try to select a part of my syntax, I can only select a few lines max. After a while the whole web page starts to act strange (automatically scrolls starts flickering).

This only happens in BigQuery studio and only for this one specific account I'm using. Any other webpage works perfectly fine and Bigquery works fine when using a different account.

What could be the issue I'm encountering and how could I possibly fix it?

I tried to clear my cache and cookies. This did not help. I also tried restarting the browser and my computer since I have nu clue what could be the issue and i thought this might help. It did not.